# iphone sdk nsstring as object - get text

Tags: iphone, cocoa, string, nsstring

I'm having an issue with a string which is being returned from a webservice. I am setting the string up in the header file, simple with

```
NSString *serviceUserID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *serviceUserID;
```

then I'm synthesizing it as normal. I can set it using

```
serviceUserID = @"4fffrdscfbg-44-06dfgf-dfgdfg-32eer456134";
```

but when it's set using the service return, it seems to save an object which I cannot access later on. So the code below doesn't work...

```
NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
serviceUserID = result;
```

The code above will output the serviceUserID string to the log window, but when I try to do the same outside of that function it crashes with no error messages. I've no idea what's up. I have tried to set the string with initWithFormat and all sorts, but nothing's working!! I just need to set the serviceUserID Variable so I can use it in other functions... is there a way to set the text that I'm missing??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also, your property should be declared as `copy`, not `retain` as it's dealing with NSString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain string value you assign to your iVar - in your example you're likely assigning autoreleased string which becomes invalid outside current scope. As you have declared property for it the correct way to do that will be:

```
self.serviceUserID = result;
```

The reason why `serviceUserID = @"4fffrdscfbg-44-06dfgf-dfgdfg-32eer456134";` works is that you're assigning string literal here - it is created at compile-time and doesn't get released at all.

Comment: For further information: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/ Mandatory reading for all Cocoa and Cocoa Touch programmers.

Comment: Thanks guys - I was so confused as to why it wouldn't work. What's more annoying is that I've done it before in other projects - but plain forgot the self.assign. Thanks

Comment: weird... i have been using strings for over a year now and occasionally run into a problem like this which i usually solve with some half ass method. Took the time to figure it out this time and voila! Thanks!